# Error: Invalid: File is too small to be a well-formed file - error when using feather in R

Tags: r, csv, feather

I'm trying to use [feather](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/feather/index.html) (v. 0.0.1) in R to read a fairly large (3.5 GB) csv [file](http://prod.publicdata.landregistry.gov.uk.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pp-complete.csv) with 21178665 rows and 16 columns.

I use the following lines to load the file:

```
library(feather)
path <- "pp-complete.csv"
df <- read_feather(path)
```

But I get the following error:

> Error: Invalid: File is too small to be a well-formed file

There's no explanation in the documentation of `read_feather` so I'm not sure what's the problem. I guess this function expects a different file form but I'm not sure what that would be.

Btw, I can read the file with `read_csv` in `readr` library but it takes a while.

Comment: `read_feather()` reads in feather files into R. Your file is a .csv

Comment: Does one of the commenters want to post as an answer, or does this warrant a "close as simple typo (thinko)" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `feather` file format is distinct from a CSV file format. They are not interchangeable. The `read_feather` function cannot read simple CSV files.

If you want to read CSV files quickly, your best bets are probably `readr::read_csv` or `data.table::fread`. For large files, it will still usually take a while just to read it from disc.

After you've loaded the data into R, you can create a file in the `feather` format with `write_feather` so you can read it with `read_feather` the next time.